# Shopify predictive search JQuery GET runs twice

Tags: jquery, shopify

I implemented following code in my theme.liquid to make my search predictive. The first part is to get the search input, then the JQuery call. It works, but unfortunately it runs twice. When I start to enter one letter in my search box, I get the alarm, I click ok, then again the same alarm. Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you!!

```
 <script>
  // Grabbing all search forms on the page, and adding a .search-results list to each.
   var searchForms = 
 $('form[action="/search"]').css('position','relative').each(function() {
 // Grabbing text input.
   var input = $(this).find('input[name="q"]');
  // Adding a list for showing search results.
    var offSet = input.position().top + input.innerHeight();
    $('<ul class="search-results"></ul>').css( { 'position': 'absolute', 'left': '0px', 'top': offSet } ).appendTo($(this)).hide();    
 // Listening to keyup and change on the text field within these search forms.
   input.attr('autocomplete', 'off').bind('keyup change', function() {
// What's the search term?
  var term = $(this).val();

      var url2 = '&resources[type]=product,collection'
      jQuery.getJSON({
        'url':  "/search/suggest.json?q=" + term + url2,
        'type': 'GET',
        'dataType': 'json', // added data type
        'limit': 5,
        'success': function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var productSuggestions = response.resources.results.products;
            if (productSuggestions.length > 0) {
                var firstProductSuggestion = productSuggestions[0];
              alert(firstProductSuggestion.body);
            }
        }
         });
      });
   });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you're sending search request on every `keyup`/`change` event trigger and alert message is shown up if there are any results.  So when you search for `blah` - 4 requests will be sent:

- `/search/suggest.json?q=b`
- `/search/suggest.json?q=bl`
- `/search/suggest.json?q=bla`
- `/search/suggest.json?q=blah`

The alert will get triggered for every request with results available by the search terms provided in the `q` param.

You can fix that by introducing a variable to keep the request and cancel it before running the next one. See below:

```
// Grabbing all search forms on the page, and adding a .search-results list to each.
var xhrSearch;
var searchForms =
  $('form[action="/search"]').css('position', 'relative').each(function() {
    // Grabbing text input.
    var input = $(this).find('input[name="q"]');
    // Adding a list for showing search results.
    var offSet = input.position().top + input.innerHeight();
    $('<ul class="search-results"></ul>').css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'left': '0px',
      'top': offSet
    }).appendTo($(this)).hide();
    // Listening to keyup and change on the text field within these search forms.

    input.attr('autocomplete', 'off').bind('keyup change', function() {
      if (xhrSearch) {
        xhrSearch.abort();
      }
      // What's the search term?
      var term = $(this).val();

      var url2 = '&resources[type]=product,collection'
      xhrSearch = jQuery.getJSON({
        'url': "/search/suggest.json?q=" + term + url2,
        'type': 'GET',
        'dataType': 'json', // added data type
        'limit': 5,
        'success': function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          var productSuggestions = response.resources.results.products;
          if (productSuggestions.length > 0) {
            var firstProductSuggestion = productSuggestions[0];
            alert(firstProductSuggestion.body);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Note the `xhrSearch` variable added to your code.

Comment: unfortunately I think the code is still executed twice, but only the part in between the beginning and the killing of the JQuery call, and only just right after opening the page. This is a problem because in my code I use input.innerHeight() in order to calculate the offset, and it's 31 in the first run and -2 in the second, which leads to an overlapping of my search results box. Any other ideas how to fix this part of the code running twice? And why this happens?

Comment: It runs for each `form[action="/search"]` element on the page

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir! I put my log "input", and search for "abc", I get two logs "n.fn.init". So this code part runs twice. Maybe the reason is, I have two search forms. One has n.fn.init->0:input-header-bar__search-input->value:"abc". Here also "clientHeight" is correct with 31. The other result for "n.fn.init" shows value:"", also "clientHeight:0", which is (sometimes?) leading to a wrong position of the created search results box. Do you have an idea how to pick the correct result in order to make sure I set the correct offset? Thank you for your help! I'm really a beginner here. Thank you!

Comment: It's not related to the original question, you better to create another one, describing the issue so people can see it and help you.